# what is the best way to parse big JSON file and insert into database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this huge JSON file.  Currently the way I am using it is:

1. Read the entire contents into a string
2. Do json_decode, get the array
3. Loop through the array one record at a time and build my SQL insert statement

Problem is, the code is ugly.  Also, some of the objects in these arrays are themselves arrays, and not all records contain all values.  I have to use isset to check if a particular value is present, or use a default value etc.  Overall, it works correctly, but the code is ugly.  Is there any way I can write this better?

Comment: To avoid uglyness you should decide what is beauty fist. I mean you should know what fields you have and what values you want this fields to be filled with. It is the only way, I think.

Comment: using json_decode() is the right way to go. But I can't tell you more about your code if you don't post it here.

Comment: If MySQL isn't a necessity you might also be interested in http://www.mongodb.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to write ugly code to generate sql queries consider using an ORM 
Propel and doctrine are the ones i have personally used.

doctrine has a method to generate an object from an array and then simply call a save method on it.

have a look at this
http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/working-with-models:arrays-and-objects:from-array

Answer (score 2):

Hard to advice without looking at the code, but I'd like to remind you about the PHP + operator for arrays, which merges two arrays non-destructively.

```
$default_values = array('Name' => '', 'Email' => '', 'Meta' => '');
$data = array('Name' => 'John'); // Only name set
$fixed_data = $data + $default_values;
```

`$fixed_data` now looks like `array('Name' => 'John', 'Email' => '', 'Meta' => '');` without a need for multiple isset() checks. (Might not be applicable to your case, hard to say without more info.)

Comment: at the moment, code looks something like: 


$json = array('name'=>'king kong', 'address'=> yet another array here, .....) 



$name = isset($json['name']) ? $json['name']:''; 
.... 
repeat the above process for address. 

then finally write the insert statement. 

it works, but it is ugly

Answer (score 0):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

If the format of the JSON is beyond your control then there's not much you can do except shuffle the pieces around the board. Do the usual thing of making your functions as small and neat as possible instead of having one large block of code. Multiple function will be easier to read and more reusable.

I tend to call this process *functional decomposition*.

Of course you can also take an OO approach and build up some nice objects that save themselves to the database and build themselves from pieces of the JSON object but this is basically the same thing (except it makes OO purists sleep better at night).

Answer (score 0):

Most databases (MySQL, sqlite etc.) prefer to work with the XML data format to [import/export data](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html).

You could convert your JSON object into XML, and then work with that.

I'm not surprised to see databases supporting JSON in the near future, but for now this is probably the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a beautiful database abstraction like [ADODb](http://phplens.com/adodb/), then you will net need to build the insert query anymore.

This is the example of insert using [ADODb](http://phplens.com/adodb/):

```
$data['col1'] = 'value1';
$data['col2'] = 'value2';
$data['col3'] = 'value3';

$result = $adodb->AutoExecute($tablename, $data, 'INSERT');
```

Since the result of `json_encode` already an `array`, it fit perfectly. If the column definition in the database allow `null`, then the a missing column in `$data` will still be a valid insert.